# SQL Server average count

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Table contains

```
 state,
 location,
 job_number,
 (and many more columns)
```

I need to query the average count of job_numbers at the state's locations.  In other words, for each state, I need to know the average count of jobs at each location.

So if there are 100 Alaska locations that have 3 jobnumbers and 100 Alaska locations that have 1 jobnumber,  the result would be 2 for all Alaska rows.  (100*3 + 100*1)/200.

Looking for Average Number Of Jobs per location in each state

Desired result

```
State   Location  JobNumber AvgJobsPerLocInState
Alaska  Loc1      Job1       2
Alaska  Loc1      Job2       2
Alaska  Loc2      Job3       2
Alaska  Loc2      Job4       2
Ohio    Loc3      Job5       1
```

Can't figure out how to do it.  To complicate it, my final query has about 50 other columns in it.  I don't want to group by all of them.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Thanks for the tips link.  I have the hardest time formatting here, need to get a handle on it.  Appreciate help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a common table expression to add a column for `count`, using the `over` clause to avoid the need for a `group by`, and then select from that cte with `avg`, again with the `over` clause. 
Something like this should do the trick:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT State 
          ,Location
          ,JobNumber -- and all the other columns
          ,COUNT(JobNumber) OVER(PARTITION BY State, Location) As CountOfJobsPerLocation
    FROM -- rest of the query here
)

SELECT  State 
       ,Location
       ,JobNumber -- and all the other columns
       ,AVG(CountOfJobsPerLocation) OVER(PARTITION BY State) As AvgJobsPerLocInState
FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

Layer the queries with either derived tables or CTEs:

```
Outer query that adds the 50+ columns
  FROM {Query that groups by State (only) and gets Average of Counts}
    FROM {Query that groups by State & Location and gets Count of JobNumbers}
```